# After inserting a single space, the cursor is more than one space away to the right position in word?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word

I received a word document that has strange formatting settings that I do not how to turn off.

The problem is: when I inserting a single space after a punctuation or character, the cursor position is more than space away from the space (see the following figure, where I turn on the display of editing mark), and when I type next character, the cursor will move to the right position. How can I turn off this strange behavior?

[image: strange behavior of cursor position]

#### edit 05-23

I made a small copy of the original doc that will reproduce this issue. The file is available from my github repo [here](https://github.com/mt1022/tmp/blob/master/space_cursor_issue.docx)

Screenshot for this file:
[image]

Comment: Try Shrinking the font size

Comment: @Sam, what do you mean by `shrinking`?  I change font size But also this doesn't help.

Comment: Try the Font spacing or position (Expanded or raised)

Comment: This is made all the more funny by the newest suggestions by our college professors to never use two spaces after a period.  To say that your software won't allow it is to say the dog ate your homework.  If I were still in school I would ask the good prof to show me how.

Comment: @SDsolar, It is a single space. But the cursor is displayed at wrong position. Anyway, interesting comment.

Comment: There's a 'Clear all formatting' button in the ribbon on the Home tab (a letter A with an eraser, right above the font colour button). I believe it reverts text to the document's 'Normal' style (so if the problem is there this wouldn't fix it)

Comment: probably you should give us a wide-view sample and how is the space between 2 words, not between a word and the indicator.

Comment: Can you share (a portion of) the document that displays the behaviour?

Comment: @mrjink, see the link in my edit;

Comment: I'm using Word 2016 on Windows 10 and I found nothing wrong. http://i.imgur.com/5iA2rsA.jpg However, it could be a normal behaviour in Word for Mac by paragraph alignment that inserts 'padded' spaces for justification.. or the file you attached was not affected by this issue.

Comment: @Sanny, I also download the doc myself and tested it. The issue is reproducible. I am using word 15.31 for Mac.  It might be normal per your might. I never saw files like this before.

Comment: I would like to see a screenshot in Mac of the same file and, if you could, enlarge the view so I can compare with the screenshot I posted above.

Comment: @Sanny. See the new edit. I inserted a single space after "figures." But there are more whitespace displayed at right of the space.

Comment: Not reproducible with your uploaded file in Word 2013 (Windows 7 64-bit) - it behaves normally.

Comment: Try to apply another font that exists in your OS (since you mentioned that you got this file, not that you created it).. and write 2 sentences (each ends with a fullstop) to see if the extra spaces occur only after a fullstop.

Comment: I've tried with Word 2016 on Windows 7 and the problem is reproducible. However, I can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. I did notice that copying all text and pasting it into a new document with "Keep source formatting" resolves the issue. Could it be that the document somehow thinks it needs full-width spaces or whatever? I tried changing the language, but that didn't help. Adding more than one space between words shows the issue as well.  http://i.imgur.com/LSRtWcr.png

Answer (score -2):

Disable this paragraph marks which is enabled in you document.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, But this does not affect the behavior of cursor positon.

Comment: It does not answer the question